# gmmktime(): You should be using the time() function

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
  $nowgmt = gmmktime();
  $monthstart = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("n"), 1);
  if (gmdate("n") > 1) {
    $prevmonthstart = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("n")-1, 1);
  }else{
    $prevmonthstart = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 1, gmdate("Y")-1);   
  }
```

the problem is that the website replies:

> Strict Standards: gmmktime(): You should be using the time() function
>   instead in  ******* on line 25 Processing LAST month Array ( [update]
>   => 1484159698 [lastmonth] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [lastname] => Henderson [firstname] => Ron [cid] => 811669 [total] => 169750 ) [1]
>   => Array ( [lastname] => Bain [firstname] => James [cid] => 1311798 [total] => 127459 ) [2] => Array ( [lastname] => Glottmann [firstname]
>   => Josh [cid] => 1275389 [total] => 123861 ) [3] => Array ( [lastname] => Fitzgerald [firstname] => Sam [cid] => 1324927 [total] => 84313 ) [4] => Array ( [lastname] => Gilson [firstname] => Matthew [cid] =>
>   1223952 [total] => 61687 ) ) [thismonth] => Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [lastname] => Fitzgerald [firstname] => Sam [cid] => 1324927 [total]
>   => 92129 ) [1] => Array ( [lastname] => Glottmann [firstname] => Josh [cid] => 1275389 [total] => 55835 ) [2] => Array ( [lastname] => Matos
>   [firstname] => Grant [cid] => 1318203 [total] => 43575 ) [3] => Array
>   ( [lastname] => Henderson [firstname] => Ron [cid] => 811669 [total]
>   => 26379 ) [4] => Array ( [lastname] => Masiel [firstname] => Jarid [cid] => 1373874 [total] => 25120 ) ) ) Array ( [local] => 0
>   [visiting] => 0 ) **ERROR: During query for previous month data, got
>   error "Query Error:42S02,1146,Table '************' doesn't exist"**

Answer (score 0):

All the arguments to `gmmktime()` default from the current time. If you leave out all the arguments, the result is the same as calling `time()`, since it returns the current timestamp. So you should use

```
$nowgmt = time();
```